# Socket survives JBoss shutdown - how to fix?

Tags: java, sockets, jboss, mina

I have a NIO-based app (uses mina-core) that starts listening on a socket when it gets `contextInitialized()` from JBoss and issues `IoAcceptor.unbind()` in response to `contextDestroyed()`.  The concrete subclass of IoAcceptor is [NioSocketAcceptor](https://mina.apache.org/mina-project/apidocs/org/apache/mina/transport/socket/nio/NioSocketAcceptor.html)

However, every time I restart JBoss, I get the following error when trying to create the new socket:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error while binding on 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:9191
original message : Address already in use
        at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioSocketAcceptor.open(NioSocketAcceptor.java:238) [mina-core-2.0.9.jar:]
        at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioSocketAcceptor.open(NioSocketAcceptor.java:51) [mina-core-2.0.9.jar:]
        at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoAcceptor.registerHandles(AbstractPollingIoAcceptor.java:583) [mina-core-2.0.9.jar:]
        at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoAcceptor.access$400(AbstractPollingIoAcceptor.java:71) [mina-core-2.0.9.jar:]
        at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoAcceptor$Acceptor.run(AbstractPollingIoAcceptor.java:457) [mina-core-2.0.9.jar:]
        at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:64) [mina-core-2.0.9.jar:]
```

Do I need to do something more than call `unbind`?

Comment: are you restarting JBoss properly?

Comment: Yes, I use the service script included in the distribution. Sometimes I simulate a failure by just killing the processes.  Either way the sockets persist past when the process is gone. Is there a socket timeout setting in Linux I can lower?